# Do decomposable modules always have submodules st. their intersection is zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $M$ is a decomposable $A$-module then we can write $M=U\oplus V$ where $U$ and $V$ are submodules of $M$.

But, is it always true that $U\cap V=0$ or we can define them to be like that and what is the story about this?

Comment: If the sum of $U$ and $V$ is direct then their intersection is trivial. Sometimes that is even given as the definition of direct sum. (there are a few equivalent definitions) What is your definition?

Comment: My defn is: If $U$ and $V$ are in direct sum, then for $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ st $u+v=0$ implies $u=v=0$. Please, check the answer below.

Comment: This really isn't about decomposability; it's about the definition of $\oplus$.

Comment: That's another definition, and the equivalence is easy to prove. What you did is correct, except you don't assume that $U\cap V=\{0,a\}$. You assume that $a$ is an element of $U\cap V$, and show that $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U\cap V=\{0,a\}$ for nonzero $a$. Then $a\in U$ and $-a\in V$. So $a+(-a)=0$ implies $a=0$.